# Focus and unfocus JavaFX application leads to "Assertion failure" on macOS Mojave using Java 8

Tags: java, macos, javafx

When I start my JavaFX (generic testing or full) application, and then click outside of focus aka on my IntelliJ IDE application, then click back on the application, it'll spam this.

```
2018-12-16 01:24:48.423 java[1549:66391] unrecognized type is 4294967295
2018-12-16 01:24:48.423 java[1549:66391] *** Assertion failure in -[NSEvent _initWithCGEvent:eventRef:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1671.20.108/AppKit.subproj/NSEvent.m:1969
2018-12-16 01:25:07.359 java[1549:66391] unrecognized type is 4294967295
2018-12-16 01:25:07.359 java[1549:66391] *** Assertion failure in -[NSEvent _initWithCGEvent:eventRef:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1671.20.108/AppKit.subproj/NSEvent.m:1969
2018-12-16 01:25:08.152 java[1549:66391] unrecognized type is 4294967295
2018-12-16 01:25:08.152 java[1549:66391] *** Assertion failure in -[NSEvent _initWithCGEvent:eventRef:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1671.20.108/AppKit.subproj/NSEvent.m:1969
2018-12-16 01:26:29.488 java[1549:66391] unrecognized type is 4294967295
2018-12-16 01:26:29.488 java[1549:66391] *** Assertion failure in -[NSEvent _initWithCGEvent:eventRef:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1671.20.108/AppKit.subproj/NSEvent.m:1969
2018-12-16 01:26:30.188 java[1549:66391] unrecognized type is 4294967295
2018-12-16 01:26:30.188 java[1549:66391] *** Assertion failure in -[NSEvent _initWithCGEvent:eventRef:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppKit/AppKit-1671.20.108/AppKit.subproj/NSEvent.m:1969
```

When I was on macOS High Sierra, it was working fine and I never encountered these issues. However with the new update to macOS Mojave, it's been giving me these errors.

I've looked around with no avail. Currently using Java 1.8.0_181 but issue is also occurring on 1.8.0_191. (Java 8)

Currently it doesn't do anything with regards to breaking the application (yet), but it does lead to the console being spammed.

What's causing this assertion failure and how do I figure out what "unrecognized type is 4294967295" is?

Currently the only fix that comes to mind would be to downgrade OS versions, but I can't request all of my users do that.

Comment: What happens if you use Java 8u191/8u192?

Comment: I will check and report back, but the compiler I'm using right now for distribution is only good for 1.8.0_181 (out of the box), which is why I've decided to stay on it.

Comment: @Slaw, looks to be the same issue.

Comment: See this one as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52323438/assertion-failure-in-nsevent might help...

Comment: This looks to be corrected in JDK 8u202.

Comment: Looks like 8u201 has it fixed, but not in 8u202.

Comment: I have 10.0.2 and I can still see it.