# How do I update JavaFX? Must I download a new version of the JDK?

Tags: java, javafx

I currently have a JavaFX project running on JDK 9.0.1, and am using Eclipse Oxygen and MacOS Mojave. I have encountered a JavaFX bug that has already been acknowledged here: [Assertion failure in NSEvent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52323438/assertion-failure-in-nsevent). It seems that I need to update my JavaFX version to get the bug fix.

My problem is: I am unsure of what I need to know to update JavaFX. From what I can tell, JavaFX came pre-installed with my JDK. How could I check my current version of JavaFX? What would I need to do to be able to install an updated version of JavaFX with the bug fix?

A quick Google search makes it seem that I would need to re-install a new JDK in order to update JavaFX.

EDIT: Trying out [How to get the version number of JavaFX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266997/how-to-get-the-version-number-of-javafx) in my project, I get `javafx.runtime.version: 9.0.1+11`

Answer (score 2):

## JavaFX 11

Read up on the changes to [JavaFX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX), now developed openly on the [OpenJFX](https://openjfx.io) project. In the current 2018 November/December issue of Java Magazine by Oracle, see the article [*The Future of JavaFX*](http://www.javamagazine.mozaicreader.com/NovemberDecember2018#&pageSet=62&page=0) by Johan Vos.

The JavaFX 11 runtime is available as a platform-specifc SDK, as a number of jmods, and as a [set of artifacts in Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx).

The OpenJFX project seems to be led by the [Gluon](https://gluonhq.com/) company, who provides this [download page](https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/) for both the current and early-access builds.