# Getting NSException on my mac when starting a java method

Tags: java, windows, macos, desktop

When I start this on my Windows laptop it goes well. But in MACOS it throws an `NSException`

```
void openInBrowserOnMouseClick(MouseEvent event) {
    if (!Desktop.isDesktopSupported() || !Desktop.getDesktop().isSupported(Desktop.Action.BROWSE)) {
        LOGGER.info("Action browsing is not supported on this platform");
        return;
    } else if (subject.getSite() == null) {
        showAlert(AlertType.WARNING, "Warning", "No site provided", "You should provide subject's site first");
        return;
    }
    try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI(subject.getSite()));
    } catch (IOException | URISyntaxException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Browsing error", e);
    }
}
```

[NSException Stacktrace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7myW.jpg)

Comment: What is your full java version and Mac OS version?

Comment: Seems like some versions of Java 8 have issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54327733/how-to-fix-nsinternalinconsistencyexception-in-tornadofx-when-running-on-macos-1